# Angular 8 - Children component not rendering

Tags: angular

I have three routes the first one including two children, first child is getting rendered but the second child is not rendered, inside url I am getting full address to it, but no templates are showing, in fact it shows its parent template, if I added **router-outlet** it renders both of them which I don't want to.

Here is the second route and its children:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'temp-details',
        component: TempDetailsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                // The problem is here
                // This component not rendering in its parent TempDetails 
                path: 'temp-credit',
                component: TempCreditComponent,
                data: {
                    title: extract('Temp credit')
                }
            }
        ],
        data: {
            title: extract('Temp details')
        }
    }
];
```

This goes inside **temp-credit.routing.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TempCreditComponent,
        data: {
            title: extract('Temp credit')
        }
    }
];
```

**temp-details.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [TempDetailsComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TempDetailsRoutingModule,
        MaterialModule,
        TranslateModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        PageHeaderModule,
        TempCreditModule,
    ],
})
export class TempDetailsModule { }
```

**temp-credit.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [TempCreditComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TempCreditRoutingModule,
        TranslateModule,
        MaterialModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        PageHeaderModule,
    ]
})
export class TempCreditModule { }
```

The **TempCreditModule** is included in both `app.module.ts` and `temp-details.module.ts`, also the component is already declared inside its own module.

The breadcrumb of this component looks like this:

`Home > credits > temp-details > temp-credit`

Comment: Can you show module.ts ? of this route

Comment: Is `TempDetailsComponent` _just_ another page?

Comment: Yes its another page with its own template, but it depends on it parent TempDetails!

Comment: @Kenny, question updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a `router-outlet` in `TempDetailsComponent`, as that's where the route children are rendered. It can happen, that there's nothing else but the `router-outlet` in `TempDetailsComponent`.

Something like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'temp-details',
        component: TempParentComponent, // <- this contains only a `router-outlet`
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: TempDetailsComponent, // <- contains the actual page
                data: {
                    title: extract('Temp credit')
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'temp-credit',
                component: TempCreditComponent, // <- contains the actual page
                data: {
                    title: extract('Temp credit')
                }
            }
        ],
        data: {
            title: extract('Temp details')
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: thanks for your interest!. By that both components will get rendered!!

Comment: So is that a success? Or a problem? Can you describe which components do you want to see on which route?

Comment: no its not, with `router-outlet` i get both of them, the second child is another page which it depends on its parent TempDetails

Comment: @swordfish expanded my answer.

Comment: So all about is to add the `route-outlet` to parent , thanks it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by creating several objects, each object has a more internal route and at the same time I deleted the components of the previously created routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path:'parent',
    component: ParentComponent
    },
    {
    path: 'parent',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        component: DetailsComponent,
        data: { title: ''}
       },
      ],
        
    },

{
    path: 'parent',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        children:[
           {path:'child-child',component:ChildChildComponent}   ///and so on
          ]

       },
      ],
        
    }
    ];
```